# Character Gaps On Comic Conversation : 6

Tags: character-identification, traditional-characters, conversation

I am reading a comic book to learn more Chinese. I have some problems with seeing some characters in this older copy of a book (the Chinese character is sometimes too dark to distinguish strokes and scanning doesn't help).Thank you for any help finding the missing characters (I don't need the translations, per se but just seeing a clear copy of the character would be helpful).

There are multiple questions because I want to show the work in context. I could break these up into smaller questions but that would not be helpful to other learners (learning conversation) and would unnecessarily clog the website.

Pane 2 ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 这是什么？：What is this?
>
> （？）（？）：

Pane 3 ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 一定很好吃!: (It is) Certainly delicious!
>
> （？）: Not sure about the repeated character on the side but guessing its a sound?

Pane 4 ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 我（？）一次吃这裡（？）西。：

Pane 5 ( ? ➜ missing character )

> 谢谢你的（？）（？）: Thank you for...

[image: Doraemon-1-6]

### UPDATE

First to restate, thank you to everyone for helping me learn more Mandarin! I hope that asking about unrecognized characters is okay on this site. I am adding the new characters and meanings to my phrase book.

Below are the accepted answers:

Pane 2：

麻薯：<del>potato</del>? ok, I saw a picture and it looks like roasted rice cakes (aka Mochi or yakimochi)

> (Turns out this was not so simple. The meaning is a reference to yakimochi - i.e. roasted rice cake. Which is funny in this context. It's a hidden joke by the author ! )

Pane 3:

咔咔：you are right, is a sound like kaka

Pane 4:

我头一次吃这种东西：It is my very first time eat something like this.

Pane 5:

谢谢你的招待：Thanks for your hospitality.

Comment: Voting to close. Google translate, hand writing option is the correct tool for this.

Comment: Your problem is difficulty with seeing characters. This has nothing to do with Chinese language. You just need to zoom in to enlarge the characters to see them. What you are doing now is littering the site with same comic questions and asking people to read for you. I don't think this is how the site should be utilized.

Comment: There are more productive ways to do this like installing an [OCR software](http://cnedelcu.blogspot.sg/2012/01/chinese-ocr-translating-scanned-or.html) and scanning the comic using a higher resolution. This is not even a translation problem as your title suggests.

Comment: Updates to this answer showed that potato can be translated as mochi or yakimochi "roasted rice cakes". Which is a bit funny in the context of the story.

Comment: Mochi is mochi, and nothing like potato...

Comment: @Semaphore Good point. However having never seen Mochi, if one is not allowed to ask for character identification on this site then I would never have learned. Even though the answer given was not 100% correct it did lead me to a new learning experience. Thanks for your help. Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pane 2：

麻薯：potato

Pane 3:

咔咔：you are right, is a sound like kaka

Pane 4:

我头一次吃这种东西：It is my very first time eat something like this.

Pane 5:

谢谢你的招待：Thanks for your hospitality.

Answer (score 2):

partial answer： pane ３：咔 [kā]，pane ４ 我頭（头）一次吃这種（种）東(东)西 pane ５： 谢谢你的招待